# OneStep Checkout for multishipping

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout, multishipping

Is it possible to display all steps of a multishipping-checkout on one page?
Currently, this only works for one shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this one it is total free

https://github.com/ecomteck/module-one-step-checkout-compatible